# How to scroll down the page to view a div in a link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

In my html page, there exists a link to sign up and a div which holds the signup form.

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="LOGO"></a>


<div>
            <form method="POST" action="signup.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fname"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lname"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Re-enter Email</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="remail"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Confirm Password</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cpwd"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Birthday</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bday"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sex</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sex"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Signup"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Cancel"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I need to scroll down to the div when the user clicks on the signup link.
Can somebody plz explain how to do that.
Thanx in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use just `HTML`, you can use an anchor tag.

```
<div><a id='form'></a>
  <form method="POST" action="signup.php">
  ...
</div>
```

Then your link will be the following: `<a href="#form">Click here to sign up</a>`

Explanation: That link goes to the `a` anchor tag with the `id` of `form`.

Comment: This also worked as same as the previous answer...Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Use the following,

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
<a href="#test">Sign Up</a>


<div id="test">
            <form method="POST" action="signup.php"> ... </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using simple HTML,using anchor tag you can scroll page to your SignUp div.
 "#" in href is used to redirect within the page.
Hope this helps

```
<a href="#mySignUpDiv">Sign Up</a>


<div id="mySignUpDiv">
</div>
```