# How to scroll to div after click on About or Contact in my menu?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to scroll to div (e.g: #about, #contact) after click on About or Contact in my menu?

```
<div class="masthead">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="muted">Name site</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at this link. It has a few nice functions that work well http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284814/jquery-scroll-to-div
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412157/how-to-scroll-down-the-page-to-view-a-div-in-a-link-clicked/14412200#14412200

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your html:

```
<div class="masthead">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="muted">Name site</h3>
</div>
<div id="about">about</div>
<div id="contact">contact</div>
```

Your javascript:

```
$('ul.nav').find('a').click(function(){
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    var $anchor = $('#'+$href).offset();
    window.scrollTo($anchor.left,$anchor.top);
    return false;
});
```

If you want to use animate, replace

```
window.scrollTo($anchor.left,$anchor.top);
```

by

```
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: $anchor.top });
```

Comment: I get an error in my JS console as soon as I click on the anchor tag- Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##details

Comment: remove "'#'+" from $('#'+$href).offset(); to avoid Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##details

Answer (score 5):

It is easier than you think.

```
  <div class="masthead">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="muted">Name site</h3>
  </div>


<div id="About">Here's my about</div>

...

<div id="Contact">Here's my contact</div>
```

By using the hash, it'll auto scroll to an element with that id (or an anchor with that `name` attribute).  If you want it to scroll smoothly you can enhance the scroll effect with a javascript library, like jquery.  See this question: [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor using jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: I tried it. This didn't work for me. Is there something else than providing href="#id" and having divs with these ids.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari The ID has to be unique. And the element has to exist on the page either at the time of load (if you want it to auto-scroll on load) or by the time you click the link.

Comment: yes, I have all that in place. Although I missed to mention that I am using Angular and routing in my app. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307824/unable-to-scroll-to-a-div-element-using-hash-in-angular-app) if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to it with HTML via:

```
<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

You can do it with CSS via:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14524399/5012320) to this question did not work for me, and there are two main problems in the provided script:

1. Need to replace `scrollTop` with `scrollTop()` if you are using jQuery
   3.x, because `scrollTop` without parentheses is a property, not a method.
2. When you want to scroll the `html` element, you should include it in the selector along with body.

The below corrected javascript is compatible with jQuery 3.x and achieves the desired scrolling effect:

```
<script>
$('ul.nav').find('a').click(function(){
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    var $anchor = $($href).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $anchor.top }, 1000);  // added duration for smooth scrolling
    return false;
});
</script>
```