# Unable to scroll to a div element using hash in Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scroll

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524297/how-to-scroll-to-div-after-click-on-about-or-contact-in-my-menu) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) that a page can be scrolled to a specific element using just a hash selector and a id attr.

But for some reasons I am unable to do it in my Angular application. Can this be due to the usage of routing  (`angular-ui-router`) in my app.

What I am trying to do is moving to a specific section of one of my page, which by the way are loaded in to a state using routing.

I have :

```
        <div class="nav_panel">
         <a class="nav_links" href="#footer">Footer</a>
       </div>
```

and

```
<div class="homeFooter" id="footer">
        <div class="social_icons">
            <span class="gplus"></span>
            <span class="fb"></span>
            <span class="twitter"></span>
            <span class="whatsapp"></span>
            <span class="youtube"></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

on the same template.

Is there a way I can make it work with routing (if at all that matters) as well or am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Did you try ```ngHref="#footer``` ?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? This should work in principle the way you have done it, but if it's not working then perhaps something else is obstructing it. As for the smooth scrolling, I assume you've got that JS code applied too? Finally, the first link you supplied seems to be related to a different topic.

Comment: @Zooly No I dint try ngHref yet. Will check that out soon and update

Comment: @webbm Sorry for the wrong link. I have corrected that. This is out of a page in a huge application. I will try to post a fiddle if possible

Comment: @Zooly `ng-href` made no difference other than that now I see `ng-href` in my DOM alongside regular `href` tag

Comment: It seems that ```<a href="anchor" target="_self">``` is working

Comment: @Zooly I gave it a try and it really seem to be working. Have to see that in detail. By the way, did you find it documented somewhere or any links.

Comment: I totaly missed to quote the link concerning my answer !
I used it some weeks ago, and I did find this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18373005/4781975
I'm writing an answer, hope it will work for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18373005/4781975), you can add the `_target`attribute to the `<a>`tag.

For your need, value on `_target` is `self`. It's an attribute compatible with all recent browser, that will redirect you to the link in the same frame as the user click (useful for SPA e.g.)

```
<a href="#footer" target="_self">Go to the footer</a>


<div id="footer">Welcome to the footer</div>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)